# I need to automatize the extraction of a logical statement (SWRL) from sentences in English

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification, spacy

(Excuse me for my English, I'm also new at this, so be gentle, thank you)

I'm trying to extract a logical statement(SWRL) from any possible sentence that contains actions and conditions

This is the kind of logical statement I'd like to obtain:

***IF (CONDITION) THEN (ACTION | NOT ACTION | ACTION OR NOT ACTION)***

I've been trying to apply some NLP techniques with **Spacy** and **Stanford NLP library**, but my lack of knowledge about grammatical English structures makes it almost impossible for me.

I'd like to know if someone could help me with this research, either with ideas or with unknown libraries for me.

**For example:**

```
import nltk
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

sent="The speed limit is 90 kilometres per hour on roads outside built-up areas."
doc=nlp(sent)
```

**Obtaining the root:**

```
def sent_root(sent):
    for index,token in enumerate(sent):
        if token.head == token:
            return token, index
```

*Out: (is, 3)*

**Obtaining the subject:**

```
def sent_subj(sent):
    for index,token in enumerate(sent):
        if token.dep_ == 'nsubj':
            return token, index
```

*Out: (limit, 2)*

**Obtaining the childrens (dependencies of the word):**

```
def sent_child(token):
    complete_subj = ''
    for child in token.children:
        if(child.is_punct == False):
            if(child.dep_ == 'compound'):
                complete_subj += child.text + ' ' + token.text+' '
            else:
                complete_subj += child.text + ' '
            for child_token in child.children:
                if(child.is_punct == False):
                    complete_subj += child_token.text+' '

    return complete_subj
```

*Out: 'The speed limit '*

**Doc ents + root:**

```
def doc_ents_root(sent, root):
    ents_root = root.text+' '
    for token in sent.ents:
        ents_root += token.text + ' '

    return ents_root
```

*Out: 'is 90 kilometres per hour '*

**Extracting the action:**

```
def action(sent):
    #Obtaining the sent root
    root, root_idx = sent_root(sent)

    #Obtaining the subject
    subj, subj_idx = sent_subj(sent)

    #Obtaining the whole subject (subj + comps)
    complete_subj = sent_child(subj)

    complete_ents = doc_ents_root(sent, root)

    return complete_subj + complete_ents
```

**Applying all the funcions**

```
action(doc)
```

**Out: 'A traffic light with signal indicates '**

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you've shown? As far as I can tell, this isn't a programming problem, but a language problem.

Comment: I just posted the code as an example of what I'm lookig for. I wonder if someone can tell me if I'm on the right track or if I should use another library or nlp technique yet unkown for me. Thank you.